# Django 'ProductDetailView' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django, request

Creating a page for an ecommerce site that allows a user to add an item to their cart. Im having issues with no object user found in the ProductDetailView. I overrode the get_context_data function to the class based view, so it will be called when they access the specific product page.

**Error:**

```
'ProductDetailView' object has no attribute 'user'
```

I'm assuming this is because the view doesn't see users, because it needs a user.objects.all()?

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView, DetailView, ListView, RedirectView, UpdateView
from django.views import generic

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required  # This is to block pages to non users using function views
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .forms import ProductForm, ContactForm
from .models import Product, Contact
from checkout.models import OrderItem, Order
from users.models import User, Profile
# Create your views here.

class ProductDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'portal/product_detail.html'


    def get_context_data(request,  **kwargs):


        filtered_orders = Order.objects.filter(owner=request.user.user_profile, is_ordered=False)

    current_order_products = []
    if filtered_orders.exists():
        user_order = filtered_orders[0]
        user_order_items = user_order.items.all()
        current_order_products = [product.product for product in user_order_items]

    context = {
        'current_order_products': current_order_products
    }

    return context
```

Comment: You have forgotten to have `self` as the first argument to the `get_context_data` method. `def get_context_data(self, request, **kwargs):`

Comment: Just seeing your comment now, why is this posted as a comment as it answers the problem?

Comment: Okay, I changed it to get_context_data(self, request, **kwargs):  but I now receive this error: get_context_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `def get_context_data(request,  **kwargs)`, you need to have `self` as first argument. You need to remove `request` from the arguments and use `self.request` to access it:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    filtered_orders = Order.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user.user_profile, is_ordered=False)
```

Comment: Okay, I changed it to get_context_data(self, request, **kwargs): but I now receive this error: get_context_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Comment: I modified the answer, you need to remove `request` from the argument list and use `self.request` instead.

Comment: Great thanks, why is that? the request now looks at self for user?

Comment: I removed **kwargs from get_context_data and now I receive this error:  
get_context_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object'
why do i need **kwargs in the get_context_data

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? You marked it correct.